# If Condition not working in my command

Tags: android, if-statement, conditional-statements

Where Is The problem can anybody help me my if statement is not working as i want it to  have checked my edittext is visible or invisible in android.

Now i have to check the condition is.,

If my edittext is visible means how can i insert the data.
If my edittext is gone means how can i insert on another data.
This is my code for if i have to check the checkbox means the edittext is invisible otherwise the edittext is visible .:

```
Button b;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.selling1);
    b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            DecimalFormat tw = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            EditText a= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.y);
            EditText b= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.a);
        Float x=Float.parseFloat(a.getText().toString());
            Float y=Float.parseFloat(b.getText().toString());
    if((a.getText().toString().equals(""))){
        Toast t= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "10000 is there", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 02, 10);
        t.show();
    }else{

            Float z=(x*y)/(100+y);
            Float p=x-z;

            EditText c= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.c);
            c.setText(tw.format(z));
            EditText d= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e); 
            d.setText(tw.format(p));
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you write the question in your own language and use Google translator to translate it to English. What you're saying about visibility has nothing to do with an empty EditText's string.

Comment: print a.getText().toString() and see what it is returning, if it is empty try this if("".equals(a.getText().toString())){Toast t= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "10000 is there", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 02, 10);
        t.show();}

Answer (score 0):

print `a.getText().toString()` and see what it is returning, if it is empty try this

```
    if("".equals(a.getText().toString())){
    Toast t= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "10000 is there", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);      
t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 02, 10);
 t.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check visibility of `EditText` the don't compare its text. Follow this instead:

```
if (a.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
    //Perform your action of inserting
}
```

Hope you understand why to choose this. Say, user entered something in `EditText`. Then you made that `EditText` invisible. At this time its text is not cleared. So you still get that text.

Hope this helps.